# .find() returns hash-symbols!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, view, find

I have this in one of my `/views/` files:

```
<%= Result.find(:all) %>
```

Result is a model.  This works fine in the console but it returns `['#,'#]` in the view.  It has recognised that I have two results but its not displaying the results.  Any ideas why?

Comment: if you're trying to debug just use debugger

Comment: use debugger yes! or use logger.debug.

Comment: `['#,'#]` is an `Array`, not a `Hash`. A `Hash` would be `{'#'=>'#'}`. Oh but you meant `#`.

Answer (score 6):

It's not a hash that is being returned, it is the concatenated string representation you are seeing.

`<%= %>` is the same as `puts` in the console. Example:

```
> puts User.all
#<User:0x00000102f98550>
...
```

If you want to see all the attributes you need to use `inspect`. Example:

```
> puts User.all.inspect
[#<User id: 2, email: "ga...
```

So:

```
<%= Result.find(:all).inspect %>
```

Still not going to be pretty output though, I guess you are doing this for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want to watch each of all the `Results` you just should do

```
<% Result.find(:all) do |result| %>
  <%= result.your_result_attribute %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes thats what I like to do.  But this gives me the same output as the .inspect.  It doesnt seem to recognise the result.model_field I am putting in.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Rails < 3

The reason why you are getting a # is because the next character is a <, your browser is 
interpreting that as a HTML element as such if you want to quickly see what that is, wrap it in a h()

i.e.

```
<%= h(Result.find(:all).inspect) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use or `debugger` to debug or `logger.debug` to output it in your development.log.

What you are doing here is `Result.find(:all).to_s` because `<%= %>` will do a `.to_s`

To debug this properly:

```
<% logger.debug "Result.find(:all): #{Result.find(:all).inspect}" %>
```